# class with vector of class

Tags: c++, vector

Sorry for bad english for first. I try search +- similar trouble but can't found.

I try to reduce example for better readability. Thanks for help.

Trouble:
I have 3 classes ("Room", "Box", "Ball") with vector of classes.
class "Room" have vector of "Box". "Box" have vector of "Ball".

After I try to get some data from  ball vector (room->box(0)->ball(0)) I get error "Expression: vector subscript out of range", but im add element with method "addBall".

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Ball
{
public:
    Ball() { name = "ball"; }
    std::string getName() { return name; }
    Ball getThis() { return *this; }

private:
    std::string name;
};

class Box
{
public:
    Box() { name = "Box"; ballList.resize(0); }
    std::string getName() { return name; }
    void addBall() { ballList.push_back(Ball()); }
    Box getThis() { return *this; }
    Ball getBall(int var) { return ballList[var]; }
private:
    std::vector <Ball> ballList;
    std::string name;
};

class Room
{
public:
    Room() { name = "Room"; boxList.resize(0); }
    std::string getName() { return name; }
    void addBox() { boxList.push_back(Box()); }
    Box getBox(int var) { return boxList[var]; }


private:
    std::vector <Box> boxList;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    Room room;

    room.addBox();
    room.getBox(0).addBall();
    std::cout << room.getBox(0).getBall(0).getName();

    return 0;
}
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
Box getBox(int var) { return boxList[var]; }
```

to this

```
Box& getBox(int var) { return boxList[var]; }
```

Your version does not return a box in the room, it returns a **copy** of the box in the room. So you are not adding your ball to the box in the room, just to a copy of the box in the room. The original box is unchanged.

My version returns a *reference* to the original box, so when you add a ball you are adding to the correct box.

You should also change this

```
Ball getBall(int var) { return ballList[var]; }
```

to this

```
Ball& getBall(int var) { return ballList[var]; }
```

for the same reason.

You should also delete these

```
Ball getThis() { return *this; }
Box getThis() { return *this; }
```

since they have no useful purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
Box getBox(int var) { return boxList[var]; }
```

you are creating a copy of the box. Adding elements to the copy doesn't change the elements in the original. Keep following your tutorial to the point where references are introduced, that should give you a hint.